# How to use Delta Table as sink for statefull spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

recently I'm working with spark stateful streaming (mapGroupsWithState and flatMapGroupsWithState). As I'm working on Databricks I'm trying to write results from the stateful streaming do Delta Table, but it is not possible in any of output modes (complete, append, update). Ideally, I would like to store all states in memory and saves periodical snapshots in Delta table. Do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Can you add more information on what kind of the transformations are you doing?

Comment: Have you looked at the spark-redis project and redis?

Can you convey more information on the issue?